# $S_n$ symmetric group of order n and elements of order n

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ symmetric group of order n. I know that left rotation $\lambda$ and right rotation $\rho$ have order n. How can I find others elements of order n?

Comment: Hint: the cycle $(1 2 ... n)$ together with the transposition $(1 2)$ generate $S_n$

Comment: Can you give me another help?

Comment: Another example : A permutation with exactly two cycles with length $3$ and length $4$ has order $12$ in $S_{12}$. In general, the order is equal to the lcm of the cycle lengths.

Comment: Thanks I want write a permutation for a generic n. If I take a, b with gcd(a,b)=1 and ab=n how write two cycles c1, c2 of order a,b such that p=c1c2?

Comment: write just one cycle of order $n$

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand.